# Array to string conversion error using hyperlinks within a table

Tags: php, arrays, string

Array to string conversion error, cant find the problem, new to php. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

$row = array(
    'username' => 'Username',
    'count' => 5
);

echo '<table><tr><td>'
    . $rowtwo . '</td><td><a href="profile.php?user='
    . $row['username'] . '">'
    . $row['username'] . '</a></td><td>'
    . $row['count'] . '</td></tr></table>';

?>
```

Comment: pl describe the error more in detail

Comment: did you add $rowtwo intentionally?

Comment: $rowtwo is an array or what??

Comment: $rowtwo is a variable that fetches an array row

Comment: $rowtwo = mysqli_fetch_array($query) or die();

Comment: really.. Why not consider reading a few tutorials present of the many on the web .

Comment: you can't concatenate array with string. Define index of array wich you want to concatenate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't concatenate array with string. Define index of array which you want to concatenate. Like this

```
<?php

    $row = array(
        'username' => 'Username',
        'count' => 5
    );

    echo '<table><tr><td>'
        . $rowtwo['index'] . '</td><td><a href="profile.php?user='
        . $row['username'] . '">'
        . $row['username'] . '</a></td><td>'
        . $row['count'] . '</td></tr></table>';

    ?>
```

Hope this will work

Comment: yes, completely forgot, thank you